# ls: cannot access '<DIR PATH passed by pipe>': No such file or directory

Tags: shell, unix, pipe, ls

I have a set of directories of my interest that I want to do sed and grep on files under only these directories. What I did is that I put all the paths in txt file, all paths are put between "" because they contain variables,

e.g. filelist.txt contains:

```
"$ROOT_PATH/test_dir1/sub_path/"
"$ROOT_PATH/test_dir2/sub_path/"
"$ROOT_PATH/test_dir3/sub_path_2/"
```

now I want to recursively grep on all files under these directories that matches my pattern and change XYZ to ABC and print it out.

`cat filelist.txt | xargs ls | grep "file_name_with_pattern" | xargs cat | sed 's/XYZ/ABC/g'`

it fails on this beginning part:

`cat filelist.txt | xargs ls`

```
ls: cannot access $ROOT_PATH/test_dir1/sub_path/: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access $ROOT_PATH/test_dir2/sub_path/: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access $ROOT_PATH/test_dir3/sub_path_2/: No such file or directory
```

Comment: cat won't expand the ROOT_PATH. Are there any spaces in the paths in filelist.txt?

Comment: No there aren't any spaces or special characters, only alphanumeric characters and dots "."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cat filelist.txt \
| envsubst \
| tr -d '"' \
| xargs -L 1 -I '@' find '@' \
    -type f \
    -regex '.*file_name_with_pattern/.*' \
    -exec sed 's/XYZ/ABC/g' {} +
```

(Separated `cat` and `envsubst` for readability of answer)

Explanation:

`ROOT_PATH` is an environment variable. The syntax `$ROOT_PATH` is a shell syntax, which is understood by neither xargs, ls, grep, cat, or sed.

It's usually understood by the shell, which means it works only if the file is read into the shell environment. However in your case it is read into a pipeline and processed without the shell being involved in the processing.

[`envsubst`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/envsubst) is a program that reads standard input, substitutes environment variables based on shell syntax, and outputs to stdout.

Likewise, usage of double quotes (`"path"` instead of `path`) is also shell syntax, and envsubst doesn't process that, so `tr -d '"'` removes the double quotes.

Now, you mentioned that you wanted a recursive grep, meaning not just 1 level down the directory tree, like `ls` would do. Therefore, `find <directory> -type f` finds all the files in the subtree under `<directory>`.
`xargs -L 1 -I '@'` will run `find` on each of these paths appropriately.
`-regex` will filter in only those file paths matching the regex.
`-exec ... {} +` will run the command, replacing `{}` with filenames, so the resulting command will be `sed 's/XYZ/ABC/g' file1 file2 ...`.

Example:

```
$ tree
.
├── [ 100]  rp/
│   ├── [  60]  test_dir1/
│   │   └── [  60]  sub_path/
│   │       └── [   6]  1
│   ├── [  60]  test_dir2/
│   │   └── [  60]  sub_path/
│   │       └── [   6]  2
│   └── [  60]  test_dir3/
│       └── [  60]  sub_path_2/
│           └── [   6]  3
└── [ 101]  filelist.txt

7 directories, 4 files
$ find rp -type f | xargs tail
==> rp/test_dir3/sub_path_2/3 <==
WXYZ3

==> rp/test_dir2/sub_path/2 <==
WXYZ2

==> rp/test_dir1/sub_path/1 <==
WXYZ1
$ cat filelist.txt 
"$ROOT_PATH/test_dir1/sub_path/"
"$ROOT_PATH/test_dir2/sub_path/"
"$ROOT_PATH/test_dir3/sub_path_2/"
$ export ROOT_PATH=./rp
$ cat filelist.txt \
| envsubst \
| tr -d '"' \
| xargs -L 1 -I '@' find '@' \
    -type f \
    -regex '.*path/.*' \
    -exec sed 's/XYZ/ABC/g' {} +
WABC1
WABC2
```

Comment: Why `cat filelist.txt |` instead of `<filelist.txt`? Granted, it doesn't make much difference to xargs; but there are enough commands it _does_ make a large difference to (`tail`, `sort`, `wc -c`, etc all can be implemented to run much faster when handed a seekable file descriptor rather than one that can only be read front-to-back w/o ability to skip ahead or query size in constant time) that it's worth being in the habit of providing a direct file descriptor rather than a FIFO whenever possible.

Comment: You can also skip the `tr -d '"'` if you have xargs handle the quotes as syntax (which it does by default when not given `-d` or `-0`). Usually this is both surprising and unwanted behavior, but the OP seems to have a use case where it's not wrong.

Comment: Also, you don't need the `-L 1` argument to xargs; it's implied by `-I`. (It also might be worth making the check for `path/` be done in `find` so it doesn't have to write filenames that `grep` will then discard).

Comment: I prefer to optimize the answer to something that a novice and read, understand, and explore, rather than for terseness or performance, which are usually a lower priority for a novice OP.

Comment: A novice learns to read the code we teach them to read and write. If we teach something that follows good practices, good practices are what they know. If we teach things that are slower or buggier, _that's_ what they know.

Comment: ...in this case, there really are bugs here: `find ... | grep 'path/' | xargs sed` assumes that the output from `find` won't include filenames with substrings that `xargs` will treat as syntactically significant. By contrast, `find '{}' -type f 'path '*/path/*' -exec sed 's/XYZ/ABC/g' --` ensures that everything makes it to `sed` just as `find` emitted it.

Comment: (as a concrete example, consider `test_dir4/Authors/Alex "Foo Bar" Smith/whatever.txt` -- the quotes in the name will be treated as syntactic rather than literal by xargs; this can also be avoided using `-print0` on the find side and `-0` on the xargs side, but then one also needs the GNU extension `grep -z`)

Comment: I edited the answer to fix the bug, but you'll notice that it makes the answer longer and less focused on the actual problem (envsubst). A single answer can be lengthy and explain a lot of shell syntax, but I think focus and readability matter more than information density in a SO answer.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and clarifications, @CharlesDuffy regarding your point of using <filelist.txt and not cat filelist.txt, I didn't know the difference until now, I usually use cat to pass text files to grep and perl one-liners and didn't know it can affect performance, Is there a big performance penalty when it comes to large files?

Comment: @Sohrab, it depends on the command. For `tail` the performance penalty is extremely large, for example, because with a direct handle on a normal file it can skip to the end (being effectively a constant-time / O(1) operation in common cases) but with `cat | tail` it has to read the whole thing front-to-back (scaling O(n) with file size).